# What does SQLite3's new() return in this ruby example

Tags: ruby, orm, sqlite

I'm following a guide to making an object relational mapping. but the guide assumes I know about the gem SQLite3 and its library. It's provided this code for me, one of many times the method `new` has been called. I found some documentation on it stating "It creates a new database object" ...it make sense on an abstract level. but I can't recall what a database object looks like, can someone give me an example of what this would return?

```
def init_object_from_row(row)
  if row 
    data = Hash[columns.zip(row)]
    new(data)
  end
end
```

is it just a hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `new` from inside an instance method creates a new object of whatever class the instance method is contained within. For example, say the method is within the `Foo` class.

```
class Foo
  def init_object_from_row(row)
    if row 
      data = Hash[columns.zip(row)]
      new(data)
    end
  end
end
```

This would return a new instance of the `Foo` class using the `data` hash as its arguments. This is not particular to sqlite3; it is just a characteristic of Ruby.